# How to Rename a Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Can someone let me know how to rename an Azure SQL Server?

How created a dummy Azure SQL Server called 'changename' and I would like to rename the server to 'newname'

I tried the following:

```
EXEC sp_dropserver 'changename';
GO
EXEC sp_addserver 'newname', local;
GO
```

But I got the following errors:

```
Could not find stored procedure 'sp_dropserver'.
Could not find stored procedure 'sp_addserver'.
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What you did there would NOT rename the database. It would DELETE (a server) is, and then CREATE it.

Comment: Hi Luuk, thanks for reaching out. Is it actually possible to rename an Azure SQL Server? The FQDN is ```changename.database.windows.net```

Comment: [How to rename/delete Azure SQL DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/273980/how-to-rename-delete-azure-sql-db)  (external lonk to learn.microsoft.com

Comment: and to rename the server [#Rename an Azure SQL database](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip146.html)

Comment: Hi Luuk, the link shows you have rename a database, not the server. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Hi Luuk, I'm not sure how to use the link you provided to change the actual server name

Comment: I don't believe you *can* change the name of the server. I suspect you would have to create a new resource and then migrate the database(s) to the new server. Why do you need to change th name? Smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Hi @Thom A, I created a server name at my workplace with the wrong naming convention. I am now being told that I need to rename the server to be inlighn with the company's name convention

Comment: If it's a new server then just delete th server and create a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once created an Azure SQL logical server cannot be renamed.

My suggestion is to create a new SQL Azure Database server with the new name you wanted to assign to the old server logical server, then [copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-copy?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#copy-using-the-azure-portal) all databases to the newly created server, finally remove the old server.